# How to dynamically edit "noRowsToShow" text?

Tags: angular, ag-grid

Related: [How To translate "No Rows To Show" message in ag-grid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40407578/how-to-translate-no-rows-to-show-message-in-ag-grid/40409005#40409005)

The problem with the solution is that it'll work only once. After the grid is visible, changes in "noRowsToShow" aren't possible. And before I'm going to search for a solution where I replace the whole grid after a language change, I'm looking for another one.

What I currently did was after every language change, I replaced the old localeText with a new tranlated one. This obviously didn't work. It looks something like this:

```
this.gridOptions.localeText = {
    noRowsToShow: this.translate("noRows", "DE");
};
```

Infact it does work but the gridOptions aren't replaced by my new one.

Is there another way to replace the localeText with a new translated one?

**EDIT:** I found the issue on Github that asks the same question but without an answer: https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues/1286

I hope he'll respond to my question

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation if you are use the localeText you are just providing the (single) language to use. if you want to use an external translator then it says to use localeTextFunc

i.e

```
var gridOptions = {

// standard grid settings, thrown in here to pad out the example
enableSorting: true,
enableFilter: true,
enableColResize: true,
columnDefs: columnDefs,

localeTextFunc: function(key, defaultValue) {

    // to avoid key clash with external keys, we add 'grid' to the start of each key.
    var gridKey = 'grid.' + key;

    // look the value up. here we use the AngularJS 1.x $filter service, however you can use whatever
    // service you want, AngularJS 1.x or otherwise.
    var value = $filter('translate')(gridKey);
    return value === gridKey ? defaultValue : value;
}
```

};

Comment: But then again localeTextFunc will be called only once at the beginning. My goal is that after every language change the grid updates noRowsToShow

Comment: You can always re-initialise the grid when the language changes. If not using html pipe type structures then you have to use code to re-initialise values that change in background code due to language.  In one of my current companys applications this is exactly how we cope with language changes. If it changes then we re-initialise/display background elements to match. But it is something we handle.